# \mediabutton --- ! Undefined control sequence

Tags: media9

The following simple source file incurs "! Undefined control sequence" error.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{media9} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\includemedia[
label=vp,
width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.45\linewidth,  
activate=pageopen
]{}{VPlayer.swf}
\mediabutton[mediacommand=vp:play]{\fbox{\strut Play}}  
\end{document}
```

The Error Information is as follows:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.10 \mediabutton
                 [mediacommand=vp:play]{\fbox{\strut Play}}
?
```

Process has been terminated ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: It compiles fine for me.